# Using Parse, how can you login into facebook and twitter using credentials stored on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, facebook, parsing, twitter, authentication

In my iOS app, I have it so that the user can login using Facebook or Twitter, and it's logging in just fine.  The only issue is that every time the user logs out and logs back in, if they try to use Facebook or Twitter it asks them to enter in their information again.  Now I know that iOS devices store the users Facebook and Twitter credentials on the phone after they've logged into their account.

So is there a way to log the user into an application using Twitter or Facebook's stored credentials on the phone, and not have to have the user enter their Facebook or Twitter credentials all the time?

Here's what I have so far.

```
- (NSError *) loginWithFacebook {

    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    if (![PFUser currentUser] && // Check if a user is cached
        ![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) // Check if user is linked to Facebook
    {
         [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            // Display some sort of loading indicator

            if (!user) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"An error occured: %@", error);
                    [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in");
                [[[[DEScreenManager getMainNavigationController] topViewController] view] setHidden:YES];
                [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] gotoNextScreen];
                [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];

                // Get the Facebook Profile Picture
                [self clearUserImageDefaults];
                [self getFacebookProfileInformation];
            }
        }];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSError *) loginWithTwitter {
    [PFTwitterUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
            [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
            [[[[DEScreenManager getMainNavigationController] topViewController] view] setHidden:YES];
            [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] gotoNextScreen];
            [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];
            [[DEScreenManager sharedManager] stopActivitySpinner];
            [self getTwitterProfilePicture : [PFTwitterUtils twitter].userId];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setUsername:[PFTwitterUtils twitter].screenName];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
            [self clearUserImageDefaults];

        }
    }];

    return nil;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the facebook / Twitter settings in the device global settings app, if the user is logged in there then those details should be used and the user should not be asked to enter anything. If the user isn't logged in there then how the login process works depends on whether the native app is installed or not, and in these cases the device doesn't auto atically get connected to yhe account the user logs into. So you can't really do exactly what you want, because that might not be what the user actually wants.

Comment: "check the facebook / Twitter settings in the device global settings app" Is there a tutorial or anything that will help me see how to do that? @wain

Comment: The settings app on the device has a Facebook section which shows login details